# Avoid creating columns which does not match any strings

Tags: r, grepl

I want to create new columns based on strings match. I am able to create but it is also creating columns which does not match. For an example:

```
      x = data.frame(name = c("Java Hackathon", "Intro to Graphs", "Hands on 
          Cypher"))
      toMatch <- c("Hackathon","Hands on","Test","java")


      ##Sentence with phrases
      phrases11 <- as.vector(toMatch) 
      res <- sapply(phrases11, grepl, x = as.character(x$name),ignore.case= 
      TRUE)
      rownames(res) <- x$name

      #replacement
      ones <- which(res==1, arr.ind=T)
      res[ones]<-colnames(res)[ones[,2]]
      res

      Output:
                         Hackathon   Hands on     Test     java   
     Java Hackathon     "Hackathon"   "FALSE"    "FALSE"  "java" 
     Intro to Graphs    "FALSE"       "FALSE"    "FALSE"  "FALSE"
     Hands on Cypher    "FALSE"     "Hands on"   "FALSE"  "FALSE"
```

I don't want "Test" column to be created as I have huge data for matching. So basically, Can we do some code changes in `res <- sapply(phrases11, grepl, x = as.character(x$name), ignore.case = TRUE)` so that it should only create columns where we have matches from 'toMatch' vector? Is there any other approach?

Comment: Try with  `do.call(cbind, Filter(Negate(is.null), setNames(lapply(phrases11, function(y) {i1 <- grepl(y, x$name, ignore.case = TRUE); if(any(i1)) i1}), phrases11)))`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `grepl()` function which gives you true or false, you can eliminate the columns with sum=0:

```
  A=sapply(toMatch,grepl,as.character(x$name),ignore.case=T)
  A[,colSums(A)==1]
     Hackathon Hands on  java
[1,]      TRUE    FALSE  TRUE
[2,]     FALSE    FALSE FALSE
[3,]     FALSE     TRUE FALSE
```